# IBM MQ XMS.NET IBM.XMS.IllegalStateException: CWSMQ0076E

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq, xms

I am receiving this error under heavy load conditions sending some messages to the producer. But my connection is created in managed mode:

```
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
```

and this error is supposed to only occur in unmanaged connections:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT09917

Has anyone else ran into this error before.

Full error:

> IBM.XMS.IllegalStateException: CWSMQ0076E: It is not valid to call the
> Send method outside XA transacttion scope on a XA transction enabled
> session.  The application called a method outside XA transaction scope
> that must be called within XA transction scope, since the session is
> used for XA transactions.  Change the application program to remove
> this behaviour.

Comment: I believe the above mentioned exception is not specific to managed or unmanaged connection mode. It can occur in any of the modes. As the exception says the Send method seems to be getting called outside of the transaction scope. What version of MQ client are you using?

Comment: Were are currently using 9.1.4, both server and client. The session is created with `transacted = false` and we are not using DTC, so I am not sure what transaction the error is referencing.

Comment: I would suggest trying with latest fix pack of MQ client i.e 9.2.0.4. Just the client only, no need to update the server. If the problem persists, it's time to contact IBM support.

Comment: How is the connection/sessions created? Multithread environment? Could you provide a sample that contains the issue?

Comment: @Shashi suggestion to upgrade the client resolved the issue.